# Robolectric print Log or Console messages

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I wrote a small test using Robolectric. There is an issue - no messages are written to the test console. In the tested code there is a lot of code like

```
Log.d("bla","bla")
```

or

```
System.out.println("bla")
```

but anyway, there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part of the code where you have applied log is not executing.so thats why log is not coming.

Comment: I used Shadow object instead of real one, and the app's code wasn't invoked.